# R Leaflet: Is it possible to show polygon label when polygon is not clickable?

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I need to show a label of polygon (with the name of the region) when moving the mouse over the polygon. However the polygon can not be clickable since I this property for another part of my code. Is this possible?

If this is not possible, another solution could be to write a name on the polygon. I don't know how to do that either. :/

Here is how my code looks so far

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

ui <- bootstrapPage(
tags$style(type = "text/css", "html, body {width:100%;height:100%}"),
leafletOutput("map", width = "100%", height = "100%")
)

# Load shapefiles
shp_Tajo <- readOGR(dsn = "./Data/ES", layer = "Aqueduct_river_basins_TEJO", verbose = FALSE)

server <- function(input, output, session){ 
output$map <- renderLeaflet({
      # Arguments controlling the looks of the basin polygon
      dopacity = 0.3
      dsmoothFactor = 1
      dfillOpacity = 0.5
      vcolors = c("red")
      leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% addPolygons(data = shp_Tajo, stroke = F,
opacity = dopacity, smoothFactor = dsmoothFactor, color = vcolors[1], fillColor = vcolors[1], 
fillOpacity = dfillOpacity, highlightOptions = highlightOptions(color = "white", weight = 2, 
bringToFront = FALSE), options = pathOptions(clickable = FALSE), label = "Tajo",
labelOptions = labelOptions(noHide = T, clickable = T, textOnly = TRUE, opacity=0.5,textsize='15px'))
  })
}
```

The shape file can be downloaded from http://riverbasins.wateractionhub.org/#find_lat_lng 
, where you have to choose spain in the drop down menu.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: please provide a reproducible example

Comment: @HubertL I have now included a reproducible example. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: That's a lot better but you haven't provided a hint on how the click event is already used in your code

Comment: @HubertL,  basically I want the user to be able to add a marker by clicking on the map even if the user click on a point within the polygon. As for for now I can only do this by setting options = pathOptions(clickable = FALSE), but then the polygon label "Tajo" doesn't show up when I move the mouse over the polygon. Is there a way to combine these two properties. Again, thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By commenting out your `pathOptions` settings, it works as you intended: you can click anywhere except for the polygon and the label of the polygon is displayed on mouse-over:

Working example:

[image]

```
library("shiny")
library("rgdal")
library("leaflet")
library("ggmap")

ui <- bootstrapPage(
  tags$style(type = "text/css", "html, body {width:100%;height:100%}"),
  leafletOutput("map", width = "100%", height = "100%")
)

# Load shapefiles
shp_Tajo <- readOGR(dsn = "./Data/ES", layer = "Aqueduct_river_basins_TEJO", verbose = FALSE)

server <- function(input, output, session){ 
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    # Arguments controlling the looks of the basin polygon
    dopacity = 0.3
    dsmoothFactor = 1
    dfillOpacity = 0.5
    vcolors = c("red")
    leaflet() %>% 
      addTiles() %>% 
      addPolygons(
        data = shp_Tajo
        , stroke = FALSE
        , opacity = dopacity
        , smoothFactor = dsmoothFactor
        , color = vcolors[1]
        , fillColor = vcolors[1]
        , fillOpacity = dfillOpacity
        , highlightOptions = highlightOptions(color = "white", weight = 2, bringToFront = FALSE)
        # , options = pathOptions(clickable = FALSE)
        , label = "Tajo"
        , labelOptions = labelOptions(noHide = TRUE, textOnly = TRUE, opacity = 0.5 , textsize='15px'))
  })

  observeEvent(input$map_click, {
    click <- input$map_click
    clat <- click$lat
    clng <- click$lng

    leafletProxy('map') %>% 
      addCircles(
        lng = clng
        , lat = clat
        , group = 'circles'
        , weight = 1
        , radius = 5000
        , color = 'black'
        , fillColor = 'orange'
        , fillOpacity = 0.5
        , opacity = 1
        )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```